# Fifo inventory in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm new to CodeIgniter. I'm trying to update the quantity of the table based on FIFO. I'm making a stock take page, if we count the physical item less than what the table has, we will reconcile and this will update the inventory table and the discard table. Updating inventory table is easy and I've done but I want to update the discard table's quantity based on FIFO. What I want is for example the quantity of item A in inventory table is 50 but when we count it physically it's 35, so when we reconcile, it should minus 15 from the discard table quantity.

| Items | Qty | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 5 | 2022-8-22 |
| Item A | 4 | 2022-8-22 |
| Item A | 9 | 2022-8-22 |

After update it should be like:
| Items   | Qty    | Date     |
|:--------|:------:| --------:|
| Item A  | 0      | 2022-8-22|
| Item A  | 0      | 2022-8-22|
| Item A  | 3      | 2022-8-22|

Please help me. If you need further clarification, do let me know. Thanks in advance

```
public function update_complete(){

        $stock_diff = $this->input->post('stock_diff');

        $counted_stock_value = $this->input->post('counted_stock_value');
        $cost_diff = $this->input->post('cost_diff');
        
        
        $reconcile = $this->input->post('reconcile');
        $barcode = $this->input->post('barcode');
        $stk_id = $this->input->post('stk_id');         
        
        
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($barcode); $i++) 
        {
            $data = array(
                'stocktake_value' => $counted_stock_value[$i],
                'stock_diff' => $stock_diff[$i],
                'cost_diff' => $cost_diff[$i],
                'status' => $reconcile[$i]
            );
            
            // Commented for testing
            $this->db->where('stk_id', $stk_id);
            $this->db->where('barcode', $barcode[$i]);
            $this->db->update('stocktake_trans', $data);

            $itemResult = $this->item_model->getStockdiscardTransByBarcodeNew($barcode[$i]);


            foreach($itemResult as $item)
            {
                $rest = $stock_diff[$i];
                if($rest > 0)
                {
                    
                    if($item['quantity'] >= $rest)
                    {
                        $rest = $item['quantity']-=$rest;
                        //$rest = 0;
                        echo $rest;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $item['quantity'] = 0;
                        $rest = $rest - $item['quantity'];
                    }
                    $this->db->where('barcode', $barcode[$i]);
                    $this->db->update('stockdiscard_trans', array('quantity' => $rest));
                }
            }
        }     
        
        
        
        // Update Stock Take
        $data1 = array(
            'reconciled_by' => $this->session->userdata('name'),
            'reconciled_at' => date('Y-m-d')
        );

        $this->db->where('id', $stk_id);
        $this->db->update('stocktake', $data1);

        // Set message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('stocktake_reconciled', 'Stock Take has been Reconciled!');

        //redirect('stocktake/complete');
    }
```

Comment: at **$rest = $item['quantity']-=$rest;  //$rest = 0;**, change to **$rest = $item['quantity']-$rest;  $rest = 0;**, move **$rest = $stock_diff[$i];** outside of **foreach($itemResult as $item)**, because for each item it will remain the stock difference.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to store the difference between the old stock and the new stock.

You can store the original quantity in a variable, update the product with the new value, and then do the difference between the original quantity and the new quantity. Finally, you store the difference in the discard table.

Is what I understood correct?

Edit 1:
Something like this?

```
$itemsModel = model('App\Models\itemsModel');
$totalDB = $itemsModel->where('Items', 'Item A')->select('sum(Qty)')->first(); // let say 50

$totalMag = 35;
$rest = $totalDB - $totalMag; // rest 50-35 = 15

$itemResult = $itemsModel->where('Items', 'Item A')->findAll();

foreach($itemResult as $item)
{
    if($rest > 0)
    {
        if($item->Qty >= $rest)
        {
            $item->Qty -= $rest;
            $rest = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $item->Qty = 0;
            $rest = $rest - $item->Qty;
        }
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

Backtesting:

-remaining qty 15

> 5 >= 15? - FALSE
> Qty = 0
> Rest = 10

> 4 >= 10 FALSE
> Qty = 0
> Rest = 6

> 9 >= 6    TRUE
> Qty = 9-6 = 3
> Rest = 0

But you need to manage, for what will happen if the remaining stock of products will be more than 0 and the quantity of products A will be 0.

Lets say we have remaining qty to 19

> 5 >= 19? False
> Qty = 0
> Rest = 14

> 4 >= 14? False
> Qty = 0
> Rest = 10

> 9 >= 10? False
> Qty = 0
> Rest = 1

What will happen for the rest = 1 when all item in our table have 0 Qty?

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I mentioned earlier, if qty of Item A is 50 in the DB and when counting physically in the store we find 35 then we will update the remaining qty in the discard table. But in our table the qty is 5, 4 and 9 respectively. If we deduct the remaining qty which is 15 (50 - 35 =15) from the first row, it will become -10 because the quantity of first row is 5 (15 - 5 = -10). We need to deduct the quantity from the first row and the remaining from the second and third until the value is fully deducted, in this case the first and second will be 0 and third will be 3.

Comment: please check the edit

Comment: Thank you again @Gireada. I'm looking into the code and will get back to you after testing. Thanks for your time , although this is CI 4 and I'm using CodeIgniter 3 but I'll try to convert it :)

Comment: Hi, I tested it, it's updating all the record of that Item Id. It should traverse and check one record at a time. It is updating all the record of Item A id to 0. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In this example we are deducting 15 from our table, it should deduct from our record until 15 is reached, when 15 is reached it should stop deducting but what's happening now is it's deducting 15 from each and every record.  Whatever you have written is perfect but it's not working like this :                                                              5 >= 15? - FALSE Qty = 0 Rest = 10

4 >= 10 FALSE Qty = 0 Rest = 6

9 >= 6 TRUE Qty = 9-6 = 3 Rest = 0

Comment: Show us the code that you convert it, by editing your post

Comment: @CodeLearner 
It should work because the code sequence is conditional on the number of records in the table and the value of the rest variable being greater than 0.

Comment: Hi @Gireada, I've shared my code. Kindly have a look.